# Download Unity3D editor without hub Ubuntu

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, ubuntu

I am tried to download unity3d editor using the hub, after some time the download menu becomes invisible and it download again from beginning. I found archives for unity editor but it is only available for windows and mac. Is there is any way to download the unity latest **2019.3.10f1** with android support without hub on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The Latest available build will be in the last post on [this official unity3d thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/).

[Standalone Linux Installer](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/292b93d75a2c/UnitySetup-2019.1.0f2):
*2019.1.0f2.*

**sha1: 56711ddafdde2554a7782c846785767e07ebdc5d**

You may need to install this additional dependency:

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```